# android timertask alternative for longrunning BackgroundService

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, timertask

im looking for a alternative to [java.util.TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

My app should start random notifications over a month.

The TimerTask can only handle one, after that it doesnt work anymore.

Does it need to get called from a backgroundService?
Or is something like AlarmManager enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for scheduling tasks in this time range. There is an official training doc in the Android documentation that you might find interesting: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Another possibility for scheduling tasks with longer periods is [`JobScheduler`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html#schedule(android.app.job.JobInfo)), though that's more tailored for scheduling network jobs.